# How do I position a div on top of another div

Tags: css, html, position, margin

The post on my website are set to show information regarding the post when the mouse hovers over it.

Currently when I hover over a post the information shows to the right, and I would like it to show on top of the post. I want to be able to margin the information to show ontop of the post in the center but nothing I input is working. 
After everything I tried didn't work I went back and set them to blank and that still didn't work.  You can see a live version at http://fallbackryleighamor.tumblr.com/

This is the current css. Any idea how I can edit it to make it work?

```
#info #date{ color:#000; border: 2px #000 solid;
text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px; font: 10px Consolas;}

#info a{ color: #000;}

#date a { width: 280px; color: #000;}

#posts{ position:;}

#date #info{position:;} #date #info{float:;} 

 {background: rgba(0, 0, 9, 0.1); float:left; width: auto; height: auto;
margin-top: ;}

#textpost #photopost #photosetpost #quotepost #quotelink #audiopost 

#videopost{background: rgba(0, 0, 9, 0.1); float:left; width: auto;
height: auto; margin-top: ;}

#date { display:none;}

 #posts:hover #date {display:block;}

 #textpost:hover #photopost:hover #photosetpost:hover #quotepost:hover #quotelink:hover 
 #audiopost:hover    #videopost:hover{display:block;}


   #date #info{
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        margin-right:0px;
        margin-left:0px;
    }

       #date #info{
        padding-top:0px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
        padding-right:0px;
        padding-left:0px;
    } 

    #date #info{
        z-index:;}
```

html

```
       <div id="date">
        {block:Date}
<a href="{Permalink}"> {DayOfWeek} {ShortMonth} {DayOfMonthWithZero}, {Year}, {TimeAgo}</a>{/block:Date}

        {block:NoteCount}
        <a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>
        {/block:NoteCount}


    <div id="info">{block:RebloggedFrom} 
reblog: <a href="{ReblogParentURL}" title="{ReblogParentTitle}">
   {ReblogParentName} 
</a>
        origin: <a href="{ReblogRootURL}" title="{ReblogRootTitle}">{ReblogRootName}<a/>{/block:RebloggedFrom}

    </div></div>
```

UPDATED WITH SOLUTION.

CSS

```
 #date{
 position:relative;
   left:-430px;
    top:95px;
    z-index:1;
       }

      #info{
    position:relative;
    left:-420px;
 top:190px;
 z-index:1;
    }

  #controls { display:none;}

  #posts:hover #controls {display:block;}
```

HTML

```
       <div id="controls"><div id="date">
        {block:Date}
<a href="{Permalink}"> {DayOfWeek} {ShortMonth} {DayOfMonthWithZero}, {Year}, {TimeAgo}</a>{/block:Date}

        {block:NoteCount}
        <a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>
        {/block:NoteCount}
                </div>
                <br>
    <div id="info">{block:RebloggedFrom} 
reblog: <a href="{ReblogParentURL}" title="{ReblogParentTitle}">
   {ReblogParentName} 
</a>
        origin: <a href="{ReblogRootURL}" title="{ReblogRootTitle}">{ReblogRootName}<a/>{/block:RebloggedFrom}

                </div></div>
```

AWESOME STUFF! I want to thank everyone who commented and helped me through this frustration. I hope my solution to this helps someone else.

Comment: information as in the date and time like `<a href="http://fallbackryleighamor.tumblr.com/post/59842880458/new-text-post"> Saturday Aug 31, 2013, 1 hour ago</a>` ?

Comment: I assume you meant add html, so I added what I thought would be most relevant. Please let me know if more is needed. Thank you for your response. The input was needed.

Comment: I tried to get it: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96798895/kjgjhg.png , is this sort of what you need?

Comment: thanks for commenting, this was what I was looking for without the option of hovering.  thanks for taking the time out to show me your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using with style `z-index:1;` and `position: absolute;`

Something like this:-

```
#date #info{
        position: absolute;
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        margin-right:0px;
        margin-left:0px;
        z-index: 0;
    }

       #date #info{
        position: relative;
        padding-top:0px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
        padding-right:0px;
        padding-left:0px;
        z-index: 1;
    } 

    #date #info{
        z-index:;}
```

Comment: I updated as you sugguested and I'm still not getting any movement. #date #info{position:absolute;
z-index:1;}  Is there any other information about my code that I can post that would help everyone understand my problem better? Thank you, for your response.

Answer (score 1):

set post z-index to

```
#posts{
 z-index:1;
}
```

and info like

```
 #date #info{
    position: absolute;

    z-index: 2;
}
```

or set z-index any value greater than 1.
 hope it helps......

Comment: This didn't seem to work either. I am changing the numbers around when I set them to -1 everything disappears. So This might not work.